# Shuffling the dataset after re-initializing the iterator in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, shuffle, tensorflow-datasets

I am using the tensorflow dataset api to feed data into the model. To the best of my knowledge I should shuffle the dataset to achieve the best performance from the model. However, since I am training for one epoch and then test for one epoch and so on... I am not quite sure if I am performing the shuffling differently. For better illustration, below is my code:

```
train_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filename_train).map(_parse_function).filter(filter_examples)\
            .shuffle(60000, seed=mseed, reshuffle_each_iteration=False) \
            .batch(train_batch_size)
train_iterator = train_dataset.make_initializable_iterator(shared_name="Training_iterator")
```

So, whenever I consume the whole dataset, I re-initialize the iterator as:

```
sess.run(train_iterator.initializer)
```

Is that safe? I am asking since while training I got the following shape for the loss function

[image]

Therefore, is the shuffling deterministic between different epochs?

Please note that I am using a seed in the `shuffle` just to make the results reproducible between different runs of the code.

Comment: What do you mean by 'shuffling differently'?

Comment: @Sharky, I mean, if during the first epoch I received images: `img1, img3, img4, img2`... Am I going to receive in the second epoch in the following order: `img1, img3, img4, img2`? Or something differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seed affects whole default graph. By setting seed you make shuffling deterministic, meaning it will maintain same order every reshuffle. So yes, you will get same order for second epoch. You can also set placeholder for seed and change it every epoch, more on this here
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13446
Without seed shuffling becomes pseudorandom